# Magento form submit button needed double click to submit

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am facing Strange behavior of submit button in magento. In cusotmer registration page, when one of the registraion field like lastname is not field and click submit button, I get validation error, its right up to here. But when I go and fill the lastname and directly click to submit button, the button moves up without submitting and when I click to it again, it gets submitted.

It because error div disappears because of which the button moves up but why the button is not   accepting click event and submit the form when all form validation is ok.

The code is exactly same with register.phtml of template/customer/account/register.phtml

Looking forward to hear from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the CSS of the error div to make it float above the page, that way it won't affect the layout as it appears and disappears.

```css
.validation-advice {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: When I put the css you mentioned above, all of the validation errors are wrapped on single line at the top of page and then later I put only z-index, this also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I only meant for the CSS to be an example, to give you an idea where to proceed. The containing element will also have to be `position: relative` and you may find you have to give the advice element a maximum width and some other styling. If this is all new to you then [go back to school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and learn about overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

In between following works for me.

jQuery(function($){
             $('#btn_create_account').mousedown(function() {

```
          var signupForm = new Validation('form-validate');
          var result = signupForm.validate();
          if(result == true) {
              $('#form-validate').submit();
              return true;
          }
          else
                return false;

        });

    });
```